# Manage subscriptions on plesk12 web pro edition

Tags: plesk

Good evening, I'm admin user of a plesk 12 server with Web Pro Edition and I want to create an user to just manage database of one domain, for that I need to manage subscriptions but I'm not able where I can manage them

Could someone help me?

Many thanks.
Juan Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create subscription "User role" with "Create and Manage Databases" permission at Subscriptions > Your subscription > Users > Roles

[image: plesk user roles]

[image: Plesk user role permissions]

Than create subscription user with this role and access to desired subscriptions:

[image: PLesk subscription user creation]

Now user you have created can login into Plesk using username and password and find webadmin at "Databases" page:

[image: Plesk Db user databses]
[image: Plesk database webadmin]

Comment: Thanks, Oleg Neumyvakin the problem is that I hadn't enabled Service Provider view...

Now I have a problem because I created domains on Power User view and now when I try to create a subscription it says that I have previously used the domain name...

Do you know what I can do? Many thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to convert domain to subscription or move domains between subscriptions.

Comment: Oleg Neumyvakin, thank for all, one question, when I create a new subscription it uses a new ip and I'm not able to put to this new subscription one ip used in another subscription. Is not possible?

Comment: It's possible, by default all new IP addresses has type "dedicated", you can change it to "shared" in  Tools & Settings > IP Addresses > choose needed IP address and will see its type.